# How to summarize specific data using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, automation

I have an Excel file that I'm trying to automatize. Column B contains data with date and time, and column C contains time. Column B has multiple rows with the same date but different times, which should be sagrigated into 3 groups, and then summarize the time in column C depending of what timeline it has in column B.

The result i want to get :

[image]

And what I'm getting :

[image]

How the data looks like :

[image]

Also adding the code I wrote in VBA :

```vb
Sub Filter_Data()

'Declare variables for the worksheet and new worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim newSheet As Worksheet
Dim currDate As Date
Dim currTime As Date
Dim startTime As Date
Dim endTime As Date
Dim timeInterval As String
Dim timeInterval2 As String
Dim timeInterval3 As Double
Dim countedTime As Double
Dim lastRow As Long
'Check if the new worksheet exists, if not create it
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
On Error Resume Next
Set newSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filtered Data")
On Error GoTo 0
If newSheet Is Nothing Then
    Set newSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    newSheet.Name = "Filtered Data"
End If

'Find the last row with data in column B
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

'Add headers to the new sheet
newSheet.Range("A1").Value = "Date"
newSheet.Range("B1").Value = "Time Interval 1 (6:00 AM - 2:00 PM)"
newSheet.Range("C1").Value = "Time Interval 2 (2:00 PM - 10:00 PM)"
newSheet.Range("D1").Value = "Time Interval 3 (10:00 PM - 6:00 AM)"

'Loop through each row in the worksheet
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        currDate = ws.Cells(i, "B").Value
        currTime = ws.Cells(i, "B").Value
        
        If timeValue(currTime) >= timeValue("6:00 AM") And timeValue(currTime) < timeValue("2:00 PM") Then
            timeInterval1 = timeInterval1 + ws.Cells(i, "C").Value
            dateInterval1 = dateValue(currDate)
             timeInterval2 = 0
        ElseIf timeValue(currTime) >= timeValue("2:00 PM") And timeValue(currTime) < timeValue("10:00 PM") Then
            timeInterval2 = timeInterval2 + ws.Cells(i, "C").Value
            dateInterval2 = dateValue(currDate)
            timeInterval3 = 0
        Else
            timeInterval3 = timeInterval3 + ws.Cells(i, "C").Value
            timeInterval1 = 0
        End If
        
        If i = lastRow Or currDate <> CDate(ws.Cells(i + 1, "B").Value) Then
            newSheet.Range("A" & newSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = dateInterval1
            newSheet.Range("B" & newSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = timeInterval1
            newSheet.Range("C" & newSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = timeInterval2
            newSheet.Range("D" & newSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = timeInterval3
                                           
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

First of all, I want to see only the counting results , not the counting process, and the results similar to what is shown at pics, thx to all !

Comment: Sounds like you need a pivot table....

Comment: When sharing screenshots it's useful to include the row/column headers, so we can relate the screenshots to the code.

Comment: @TimWilliams thank you for your remarks,  i can't add new here ;( As you can see at screens that I added at the description, at the new worksheet there are 4 headers for the first 4 columns , and no headers for other rows. I would like to get the result that shows me the day number at 1 column and then the summarized time , that follows into specific timilines , at the others. At this moment in couts the time for the 1 and 3 timelines (for the 2 results can't be translated to the time value, idk why), but shows me all the results before the final one, what makes them unreadeble

Comment: @FrankBall thank you for advice, I appreciate this. Pivot table was helpful here for sure if I would like to do the work manually, maybe I don't have enough knowleage to also automatize the creation of this kind of table and other stuff ;( It's criticaly import to solve this problem using VBA, if you know how to combine PT and VBA via code, let me know please !

Comment: Once your Pivot Table has been created, it should be just a simple matter of refreshing it.  If you're creating this from scratch every time, it should be pretty simple.  If you are creating this from scratch every time, try using the macro recorder to get the basics of creating the Pivot Table and then tweak the code from there.

Comment: Can you share a workbook with sample data?